# POST request response being sent in weird format

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, http-headers

I intend to send my server response in the following format
[Api Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0D7P.png)

I did the following

```
            headersR.add("response_code", "OK");
            headersR.add("cmd_code", "SET_FK_NAME");
            headersR.add("trans_id", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000000));

            JSONPObject map1 = new JSONPObject("fk_name", "jj");

            return new ResponseEntity<>(map1, headersR, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I was getting a negative response from the other side so I checked Wireshark(Had a hard time logging my response body). And I got this in Wireshark.

[Wirehark Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX0yP.png)

The response body is Definitely not JSON.
How can I fix this?

Comment: You should post the actual output here and not a link.  Looks like JSON to me!

Answer (score 0):

The response body `fk_name("jj")` is not JSON, it's [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) -- Browser would take the function name `fk_name` and try to execute it with `"jj"` as parameter.

The root cause is you are using [JSONPObject](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/JSONPObject.html#JSONPObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), whose constructor accepts 2 parameters: a function name, and the data value. Not the expected JSON key and value.

To fix this issue and return `{"fk_name":"jj"}`, remove the JSONPObject stuff and use code as follow:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"fk_name\":\"jj\"}", headersR, HttpStatus.OK);
```